# ActiveRecord Rails - create a batch of empty records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my rails app, I have a model say 'Server' that has many 'VirtualMachine'. When a server record is configured to have 50 virtual machines, then I want to create 50 empty records of VirtualMachine immediately.
    1)   id: 1, start_time: nil, space: nil
    2)   id: 2, start_time: nil, space: nil
    3)   id: 3, start_time: nil, space: nil
    4)   id: 4, start_time: nil, space: nil
...
    50)  id: 50, start_time: nil, space: nil

I know this is possible with a for loop and create/new. But is there an ActiveRecord way to do this without a loop so that I reduce the number of calls made from my app to the database?

thanks,
Greg

Comment: Do it as a background job with a block: `n.times { Model.create! }`

Comment: @Emu still really ineffective even if it does not tie up web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [activerecord-import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import). It handles bulk inserts like you described, while keeping the number of ActiveRecord queries to a minimum. And it's probably a good idea to do this in a background job since you are creating so many records.

Comment: This works good. And I can use delete_all for bulk deletes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create multiple records with no actual data you want to write a single SQL query that inserts all the records at once rather than using `.create` which will create 50 seperate queries.

ActiveRecord has no built in provisions for mass inserts. You can either use a gem or write your own which is pretty trivial for this use case.

You can insert multiple rows at once with something like:

```
INSERT INTO virtual_machines (server_id) VALUES (1), (1),...
```

You can use simple string manipulation to add all those values:

```
"INSERT INTO virtual_machines (server_id) VALUES " + Array.new(50, "(#{id})").join(', ')
```

You should be able to ignore all the columns without values since they should be handled by DB defaults anyways.

To execute a SQL statement use `self.connection.execute`. Wrapping it in a transaction may be prudent:

```
class Server < ApplicationRecord
  def self.create_with_children(**attributes)
    self.transaction do
      record = self.create!(attributes)
      self.connection.execute(
        'INSERT INTO virtual_machines (server_id) VALUES ' + 
        Array.new(50, "(#{record.id})").join(',')
      )
      record
    end
  end
end
```

Since its a single query the execution time will most likely be comparable to inserting a single row and using a background job is premature optimization.